# PHP Array Swap in dynamic input

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two dynamic arrays of integer, one thing that I wanna do is swap value inside my array-based on input.

For example my two arrays:

```
$myArray_a = 
Array
(
  [0] => 21306000
  [1] => 50627412
  [2] => 2560227681
  [3] => 2796924085
  [4] => 0
  [5] => 0
)

$myArray_b = 
Array
(
  [0] => 505909732
  [1] => 400831144
  [2] => 2693575413
  [3] => 3072271817
  [4] => 5277000763
  [5] => 4944000763
)
```

And my expected output was when the input = 3, array B index number 4 and 5 swap to array A in the same index.

```
$output = 
Array
(
  [0] => 21306000
  [1] => 50627412
  [2] => 2560227681
  [3] => 2796924085
  [4] => 5277000763
  [5] => 4944000763
)
```

I want to switch, is there an easy way to do this? Or will it require a loop + creating a new array?

Comment: Does "3" mean "_only use upto index 3 from the first array_" ?

Comment: yes, absolutely right sir @Scuzzy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your are using an numeric index, you could leverage array_slice

This will create an array with the first four entries, then append the second array skipping existing keys.

```
$count = 4; // which is 3 + 1
$a = [21306000,50627412,2560227681,2796924085,0,0];
$b = [505909732,400831144,2693575413,3072271817,5277000763,4944000763];

$output = array_slice( $a, 0, $count ) + $b;

//Array
//(
//    [0] => 21306000
//    [1] => 50627412
//    [2] => 2560227681
//    [3] => 2796924085
//    [4] => 5277000763
//    [5] => 4944000763
//)
```

Comment: it doesn't work sir, it just swaps only on index number 0 in array A and $counts, but the rest of it uses array B.

Comment: it should be swap array B into array A just on $count and the rest of it using array A.

Comment: Then I'm not following your question sorry, https://3v4l.org/9hYCc returns the same as your output example. An array with A[0-3] and B[4-5] is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with,

```
    $index = 3;
    $result = $B;
    for($i = 0; $i<= $index; $i++){
        $result[$i] = $A[$i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach`

```
 foreach($myArray_a as $k => &$v){
  empty($v) &&  isset($myArray_b[$k]) ? ($v = $myArray_b[$k]) : ''; 
 }
```

DEMO :- https://3v4l.org/nRj68

Comment: Nothing in the question to suggest emtpy values should be replaced, more so if the index is > than given input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = [2,3,4,5,0,0];
$b = [20,30,40,50,60,70];

$counter = 0;
$out = array_map(function($m, $n ) use (&$counter)
{
    return $counter++>3 ? $n : $m;
}, $a, $b);

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 4,
  3 => 5,
  4 => 60,
  5 => 70,
)
```